# How to type react-currency-masked-input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When i was build my project, this component ware crash de process

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I used this solution.

```
declare module 'react-currency-masked-input' {
  import { Component } from 'react';

  export interface CurrencyMaskedInputProps {
    name?: string;
    value?: any;
    onChange?: (event:Event,value:any) => void;
    onBlur?: (event: { target: { name: string, value: string } }) => void;
    onFocus?: (event: { target: { name: string, value: string } }) => void;
    prefix?: string;
    suffix?: string;
    thousandsSeparatorSymbol?: string;
    decimalSymbol?: string;
    decimalPlaces?: number;
    inputMode?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    readOnly?: boolean;
    customInput?: React.ReactNode;
    className?: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
  }
    
  export default class CurrencyMaskedInput extends Component<CurrencyMaskedInputProps> {}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).